# How to Prepare a Py Code to Convert into an Exe File

Tags: python, exe

I have written a small code that calculates and classifies BMI. The code is as follows:

```
weight= float(input("Put Your weight in Kilograms: ")) 
height= float(input("Put Your Height in Metres: "))
heightsqr= height**2
if weight/heightsqr <18:
    print ("Your BMI Is", weight/heightsqr, "and You Are Underweight")
elif weight/heightsqr < 26:
    print("Your BMI Is", weight/heightsqr, "and You Are Normal")
elif weight/heightsqr <31:
    print("Your BMI Is", weight/heightsqr, "and You Are Overweight")
else:
    print("Your BMI Is", weight/heightsqr, "and You Are Obese")
```

The code works when running in py, but, when it is converted to a portable exe file, it displays inputs and disappears without returning the output.
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you converting the application to a .exe?

Comment: I use Auto-py-to-exe to convert the py file into exe. I also use pyinstaller but I prefer Auto-py-to-exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the after entering the inputs the calculation gets done and the result gets printed, but because of your conversion it assumes your program has terminated and it closes the window.

You could add another input value to your code so that it doesn't automatically close with input:

`input('Press any key to close program.')`